# Disable Sorting of Many2one field in odoo

Tags: odoo, odoo-15

In `Odoo15` have a many2one field related to `sale.order` in my custom model, I am passing a domain of some specific `id` of `sale.order` which is to be displayed in the many2one field dropdown.

Example:
let's assume I have a character field of name `custom_field_char`

Now let's say in `sale.order` there are 10 records in total and I have created a onchange method that updates my `custom_field_char`, in this example after computation `custom_field_char` updated as `[["id", "in", [1072, 1102, 1099]]]`.

I have provided the `custom_field_char` field as domain to my `many2one` field, as the dropdown list it gets automatically sorted by name in alphabetical order but I dont want to sort it, I want just to display it in the same order as I have passed in domain.

If we consider `1072` id has the name `B`, `1102` id has the name `Y`, and `1099` id has the name `R`, I want it in dropdown as `B,Y,R` but now its dispayed as `B,R,Y` as per the alphabetical sequence

Please suggest to me what should i do in order to achieve it.

Answer (score 1):

I have already faced the same issue. A workaround was to create a model in-between ("your.between"), with a field sequence to sort the sale orders the way you want (`_order = "sequence"`)...

```
YOUR-CUSTOM-MODEL             YOUR-BETWEEN-MODEL                 SALE-ORDER-MODEL
bw_ids = O2M(your.between)    cust_id = M2O(your.custom)       
                              sol_id = M2O(sale.order)
                              sequence = Fields.Integer
```

[image]

Comment: i dont want it in my custom model, if that was in my custom model then you were right i will go with this one, 

i have creaed a `many2one` of  `res.users`  field in sale.order only, and i dont want to sort i want it to show as i pass the values in my domain

Comment: then, maybe you could consider using a javascript approach...